# How do I pull the names of all the the records and put it in a picklist? (Lightning component)

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

Here is the picklist in the component:

```
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">    
                <ui:inputSelect aura:id="project" label="Project"
                    class="slds-input"
                    labelClass="slds-form-element__label"
                    value="{!v.newCase.Project__c}" />
            </div>
```

This is the JavaScript controller that updates the picklist with the values.

```
    var populateprojects = component.get("c.getProjects");
    var inputsel4 = component.find("project");
    var projects = [];   

    projects.push({"class" : "optionClass", label: "- Please Select -", value: ""});

    populateprojects.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        for(var i=0;i< a.getReturnValue().length;i++){
            projects.push({"class": "optionClass", label: a.getReturnValue()[i], value: a.getReturnValue()[i]}); }   
        inputsel4.set("v.options", projects);
    });
```

Lastly, the Apex controller code:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Project__c> getProjects(){
        return [SELECT Name FROM Project__c];
    }
```

Currently, I have one record in Projects and this is the what it says for that record in the picklist:

[object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add the entire *object* (record) to the list, so you got what you asked for. Instead, set the individual values:

```
projects.push({"class": "optionClass", 
               label: a.getReturnValue()[i].Name, 
               value: a.getReturnValue()[i].Id});
```